# How to include 3rd parthy library in webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Does anyone knows how to add a 3rd party library into webpack and use it inside vue component script

I do not want to use npm

Answer (score 1):

When I want to import 3rd party libraries inside my code, using webpack bundling system, I use `script-loader`. Here's the [link](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader#inline)

And you do

```
import MyLibrary from 'script-loader!./path/to/3rd/party/library.min'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 'script-loader' is not supported by node.js

Comment: So I suggest to use `import-loader` inside your webpack configuration together with `ProvidePlugin` to make available everywhere

Comment: still not working. to be more clear I want to load stripe.js cdn  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

inside my vue .js compoent script. I included it in my index.html file but didn't work. do you think it is possible?